# Grabbing only one object out of an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am using MongoDB and I am trying to grab a specific object based on its _id and all of the sibling elements as well. For example my array looks like this:

```
"blogs": [
    {
        "body": "default valuee",
        "header": "another first",
        "_id": "1234"
    },
    {
        "body": "second default value",
        "header": "second",
        "_id": "5678"
    }
]
```

And I am trying to grab the values that are beside the _id of **1234** (so the body,header and _id fields of just that object). I have tried a few Mongo queries but with no such luck. Any help would be great, cheers

My function is :

```
module.exports = function findBlog(db, id, callback){

var UserCollection = db.collection('users') //connect to business collection

UserCollection.findOne({ 'blogs._id': id }, {body: 1, header: 1, _id: { $elemMatch: { _id: id}}},function (err, user) {

    if (err){
        return callback({response: "3"})                              
    }else if(!user){
        return callback({response: "4"})
    }else {
        return callback({response: "2",data:user.blogs})
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you using any specific language or just the CLI? Take a look at the MongoDB doc [*specify-equality-condition*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#specify-equality-condition)

Comment: Hi, I am using NodeJs, Express, mongoose for back-end. And I am trying to write a query for my findblog function

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code you have so far (for your findBlog function)?

Comment: I've just added the function

Comment: Do you have a blog scheme? Why are you going through the user collection to get a specific blog by its id?

Comment: I am passing the route id via react routing v4 to my blog component, and when users go to that route I fetch the relevant data for that blog page (identified by its id as I was hoping to just grab only one relevant object rather than grabbing all of the objects)

Comment: What I mean is, if you have a blog collection, you can simply do `BlogCollection.findOne({ _id: id }, function (...) { ... })`.

Comment: Yup, I was thinking that - however there are only going to be a few users so I thought I could just chuck them into the relevant users' blog. But I am seeing that this is causing issues so I might just do what you recommend, and create the collection and do some extra linking collections. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in a comment on the OP's question, the best way to to work this out is to create a **Blog collection**. You can then query this collection directly instead of querying the User collection.

You can still have the `blogs` property in the User model by linking a blog to a user. (see the Mongoose documentation on [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html))

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like this,

**If you want all fields from blogs and user you can directly use**,

```
UserCollection.find({ 'blogs._id': id },  { blogs:{ $elemMatch:{ _id: id }}},function (err, user) {
        if (err){
            return callback({response: "3"})
        }else if(!user){
            return callback({response: "4"})
        }else {
            return callback({response: "2",data:user.blogs})
        }
      });
 }
```

**If you need specific fields:**

First parameter you will add condition: `{ 'blogs._id': id }`
Second parameter you will add fields required: `{ "blogs.body": 1,"blogs.header": 1 }`

```
UserCollection.findOne({ 'blogs._id': id }, { "blogs.body": 1,"blogs.header": 1 },function (err, user) {
    if (err){
        return callback({response: "3"})
    }else if(!user){
        return callback({response: "4"})
    }else {
        return callback({response: "2",data:user})
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answers, however the callback for **data:user** returns all of the user object which includes all of the objects inside the blogs array

Comment: you are getting all users? or only users those are having that blog

Comment: I have only one user, so it is just returning that whole profile of that one user which the blogs array is in.

Comment: `UserCollection.find({ 'blogs._id': id },  { blogs:{ $elemMatch:{ _id: id }}}`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help I think I am just going to a create a collection for the blogs, as things might be easier - thanks for the help though!

Comment: checked with elemMatch?

Comment: Yeah I did, still returned all of the blogs array. Thanks for the help though!